# find parent td tag and disable click

Tags: javascript, onclick

Find main parent td tag and disable the click event:

**HTML:**

```
<tr>
<td id="" class="tg-tue">2:30</td>
<td id="selectedtimetemptue230" onclick="makeChangeTuesday(3,0,1,'tuesday',0,'2:30',0)" class="tg-tue availablepopup">
<a href="#" class="occupypopup"><span class="tempclr noclr text-bold">X</span></a><br>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td id="" class="tg-tue">3:30</td>
<td id="selectedtimetemptue330" onclick="makeChangeTuesday(3,0,1,'tuesday',0,'2:30',0)" class="tg-tue availablepopup">
<a href="#" class="occupypopup"><span class="tempclr noclr text-bold">X</span></a><br>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td id="" class="tg-tue">4:30</td>
<td id="selectedtimetemptue430" onclick="makeChangeTuesday(3,0,1,'tuesday',0,'2:30',0)" class="tg-tue availablepopup">
<a href="#" class="occupypopup"><span class="noclr text-bold">X</span></a><br>
</td>
</tr>
```

**Jabascript:**

```
var tempclr = $(".tempclr").length;
if(tempclr > 0) {
    // this will add class for first 2 tr tags                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    $(".tempclr").addClass('test123');
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please provide more information on what you want to achieve and what you have already tried. With this information, it's very hard to give a correct answer.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean the parent `TD`?

Comment: @Banzay if `tempclr` clss is found then disable click. as remove on click event.

Comment: @RemcoBravenboer I am not aware how to find parent tags. I can count total `tempclr` class in the page.

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane actually parent TD will be good. Can we remove onclick event from there?

Comment: read documentation for .parent() or .closest()

Comment: @epascarello I am not getting. Please help!

Comment: Why are all the `td` IDs the same? Isn't ID for single use, shouldn't those use a class instead?

Comment: @Bman70 edited the question. Actually I did copy that's why it was same!

Answer (score 0):

This disables the `onclick` in every table cell where class `tempclr` is found:

```
var tabdat = document.querySelectorAll('table tr td:last-of-type');
var href = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i < tabdat.length; i++) { 
if(href[i].innerHTML.indexOf('tempclr') != -1 ) {
tabdat[i].onclick = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Try putting the script at the bottom of the HTML, at least below the table. Good luck! :)